# What will be the Information Gain for the variable that will be placed in the root of the tree?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to solve this problem from Stepic:

> Download a dataset with three variables: sex, exang, num. Imagine that
> we want to use a decision tree to classify whether or not a patient
> has heart disease (variable num) based on two criteria: sex and the
> presence / absence of angina pectoris (exang). Train a decision tree
> on this data, use entropy as a criterion. Specify what the Information
> Gain value will be for the variable that will be placed in the root of
> the tree. The answer must be a number with precision 3 decimal places.

That's what I did:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X, y)
tree.plot_tree(clf, filled=True)

l_node = clf.tree_.children_left[0]
r_node = clf.tree_.children_left[1]
n1 = clf.tree_.n_node_samples[l_node]
n2 = clf.tree_.n_node_samples[r_node]
e1 = clf.tree_.impurity[l_node]
e2 = clf.tree_.impurity[r_node]
n = n1 + n2

ig = 0.996 - (n1 * e1 + n2 * e2) / n
```

[image]

Information Gain is 0.607. But when I enter Information Gain, the answer is not correct.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating the Decision Tree using the desired criterion: `entropy`. If you don't specific anything, the algorithm will be using `gini` criterion as default (as you can see in the plot)

The code should be:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy")
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Sometimes, changing the criterion can make change your tree (in this case I doubt), but you will be able to see the entropy in every split, which can be very helpful in your task.